# How to evaluate a program's runtime?

Tags: c++, profile

I've developed a simple program and want to evaluate its runtime performance on a real machine, e.g. my MacBook.
The source code goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

int main () {
    auto beg = std::clock () ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1e8; ++ i) {

    }
    auto end = std::clock () ;
    printf ("CPU time used: %lf ms\n", 1000.0*(end-beg)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) ;
}
```

It's compiled with gcc and the optimization flag is set to the default.
With the help of bash script, I ran it for 1000 times and recorded the runtime by my MacBook, as following:

```
[130.000000, 136.000000): 0
[136.000000, 142.000000): 1
[142.000000, 148.000000): 234
[148.000000, 154.000000): 116
[154.000000, 160.000000): 138
[160.000000, 166.000000): 318
[166.000000, 172.000000): 139
[172.000000, 178.000000): 40
[178.000000, 184.000000): 11
[184.000000, 190.000000): 3
```

"[a, b): n" means that the actual runtime of the same program is between a ms and b ms for n times.

It's clear that the real runtime varies greatly and it seems not a normal distribution. Could someone kindly tell me what causes this and how I can evaluate the runtime correctly?

Thanks for responding to this question.

Comment: sorry, I compile it by g++, not gcc

Comment: That largely depends on how busy your system is. I indeed would expect a lower deviation on an otherwise idle system. You can try to call the process with `nice -n -10` to improve the scheduling priority and see, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tested your program locally (linux) and 99% of the tests are inside a 0.5ms time interval. No test was outside a 10ms interval.

Comment: @Scheff, with default optimization level (`-O0`) the for loop seems to be not optimized out. OP uses default optimization level.

Comment: @Scheff yeah, the default optimization level is -O0 and the for loop is not optimized out.

Comment: @Ctx perhaps the reason is that your compiler optimized out the loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Benchmarking is hard!

Short answer: use [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

Long answer:
There are many things that will interfere with timings.

- Scheduling (the OS running other things instead of you)
- CPU Scaling (the OS deciding it can save energy by running slower)
- Memory contention (Something else using the memory when you want to)
- Bus contention (Something else talking to a device you want to talk to)
- Cache (The CPU holding on to a value to avoid having to use memory)
- CPU migration. (The OS moving you from one CPU to another)
- Inaccurate clocks (Only CPU clocks are accurate to any degree, but they change if you migrate)

The only way to avoid these effects are to disable CPU scaling, to do "cache-flush" functions (normally just touching a lot of memory before starting), running at high priority, and locking yourself to a single CPU. Even after all that, your timings will still be noisy, so the last thing is simply to repeat a lot, and use the average.
This why tools like [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) are probably your best bet.

[video from CPPCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk)
Also available live [online](http://quick-bench.com/)

Comment: Average is not necessary the best. median for example allows to sort out bound artifacts. Lowest is also to be considered, as the one with the less interferences (even if less reproductible/comparable between runs).

Comment: @Jarod42: https://github.com/google/benchmark#reporting-statistics. You can always argue about which average is best, it mostly depends on what you are using it for. Expect variance though. It's almost impossible to remove.