# gcc -O2 optimize to strange behavior, is this a bug?

Tags: c++, algorithm, ubuntu, gcc, optimization

I am working on my math homework and have written a c++ version of the [SJT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).

When I tried to test the time cost of this code with input `n=12`, I got different results.
You can see that there are three calls of the `init` in `generate`, they are not redundant.
If I keep all of them, the time cost is `1200+ms`. However, if I delete the second or the third `init`, the time cost becomes `600+ms`. How could the call of `init` even after the `neighbour_exchange` affect the time cost? Is this a bug of gcc -O2 optimization?

Compiled with -O2, the assembly code is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/q8PoWjqx3).

My operating system is ubuntu 20.04, I've tried both gcc (`x86_64-linux-gnu`) version `9.3.0` and `10.3.0`

Here is the code.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

// #define SHOW
struct Permutation {
    const static int MAXN = 100;
    int N;
    char s[2*MAXN]; // output string
    int r[MAXN]; // radix number

    inline void init() {
        memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
        memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            s[i] = 'a' + i - 1;
        }
    }

    void generate(int n) {
        N = n;
        init();
        init();
        auto start = clock();
        neighbour_exchange();
        printf("neighbour_exchange: %lf\n", (double)(clock() - start)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        init();
    }

    // SJT algorithm with Even's speed up
    void neighbour_exchange() {
        // idx_N is the index of the largest element
        // t_N is the current direction of the largest element
        int idx_N = N, t_N = -1;
        while (true) {
            #ifdef SHOW
            puts(s+1);
            #endif

            int i = N;
            r[i] += 1;
            
            // if the N-th radix doesn't carry
            // just use the old direciton and move N
            // else we should find the largest non-carry element and move it
            if (r[i] < N) {
                char c = s[idx_N];
                idx_N += t_N;
                s[idx_N-t_N] = s[idx_N];
                s[idx_N] = c;
                continue;
            }
            // this is safe because if r[1] == 1, r[0] will be set to 1 
            // so in the next loop r[0] != 0, which will break the while loop
            // and then the function will end
            while (r[i] == i) {
                r[i] = 0;
                r[--i] += 1;
            }
            if (i == 0) break;

            // some computation of the direction and movement of the elements
            int j = 1;
            char c = 'a'+i-1;
            while (s[j] != c) j++;

            int t = (r[i-1] ^ (~i & r[i-2])) & 1;
            t = (t << 1) - 1;
            c = s[j+t]; s[j+t] = s[j]; s[j] = c;
            t_N = (r[N-1] ^ (~N & r[N-2])) & 1;
            t_N = (t_N << 1) - 1;
        }
    }
} perm;

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    perm.generate(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: clock() is not precise.

Comment: Also worth noting that the second and third calls to `init()` _are_ redundant.

Comment: Please note that, in the Compiler Explorer link, `auto start = clock();` is *before* the two `init()`. Consider using [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) or [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) to [measure times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387586/measuring-execution-time-of-a-function-in-c), but also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001446/how-to-evaluate-a-programs-runtime.

Comment: @Hasturkun, they are not redundant in term of the strange time cost. Actuallly I'm comparing several different algorithm and the `init` will be caled before every algorithm, here is the whole code https://godbolt.org/z/Pxeq8dxjq. These two extra calls of `init` does cause the strange behavior.

Comment: @Bob__, I think this doesn't matter the main time cost, the point is why this two extra calls of `init` make the time cost doubled.

Comment: I've tried `std::chrono::steady_clock` and get the same result. It doesn't matter how I record the time, the key point is that the time cost doubled! If I set `n=13`, the time will be 12s and 25s, a huge difference. 
I just want to know why the extra calls of `init`, which seems not to affect the execution of `neighbour_exchange` function, will double the time cost?