# A strange bug of g++9.3.0 -O2 on linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, optimization, time

I've met a strange bug of g++9.3.0 -O2 on linux

The code below is converted from my code of the SJT algorithm.
If I keep the last line `init` in `generate`, the time cost is `1200+ms`.
if I delete it, the time cost is `600+ms`.

This bug appears on ubuntu20.04 with g++9.3.0. I've tested it on win10 and macOS with g++9.3.0, the bug doesn't appear. I've also tested it on linux with g++8 and g++10, the bug doesn't appear, either.

Here is the code. The original question is [69468547](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468547/gcc-o2-optimize-to-strange-behavior-is-this-a-bug).

I want to know what causes this strange "time cost double" behavior?

20211008: I reproduce this bug in another way. Here is the [whole code](https://godbolt.org/z/vdTEjb3qz).I execute the `strange_func`(SJT algorithm) twice in `generate`, the first one's time cost is `653ms` and the second one's is `1322ms`. You can reproduce the bug with gcc9.3.0 on linux. I've also tried gcc10, there is no bug.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
#define MAXN 100

struct Permutation {
    int N;
    char s[2*MAXN];
    int r[MAXN];

    inline void init() {
        memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
        memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));
    }

    void generate(int n) {
        N = n;
        init();
        auto start = steady_clock::now();
        strange_func();
        auto end = steady_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        printf("time cost(ms): %ld\n", duration.count());
        init();
    }

    void strange_func() {
        int k = N, t = -1;
        while (true) {
            r[N] += 1;
            if (r[N] < N) {
                char c = s[k]; s[k] = s[k+t]; s[k+t] = c;
                k += t;
            } else {
                int i = N;
                while (r[i] == i)
                    r[i] = 0, r[--i] += 1;
                if (i == 0) break;
                t = 0;
            }
        }
    }
} perm;

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    perm.generate(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also, what is the value of `n` to run this with?

Comment: sorry I forgot the question. I've added it at the last line.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a separate question from your original (which you even linked in this question)

Comment: Except printing duration, your program has no side effects. Moreover with `init` case, memory content is even know at the end.

Comment: Can you try compiling it without optimizations?  The option for that is `-O0`.

Comment: @David, There is no bug with -O0.

Comment: @Jarod42, the original version is SJT algorithm, it will print all the permutations of  1~N. I only keep the bug related code in this question.

Comment: Can you reproduce on godbolt (or other online compiler)?

Comment: The two variant appear to use a similar assembly code. Thus, I am not sure this is a GCC bug. Can you provide the assembly code you get for the two implementation (if possible with the address of the opcode as this can impact the result and likely does)? Can you run the program using linux `perf` and put the report in your question? Providing the exact processor name should also help us.

Comment: @Jarod42, I reproduced it in another way, you can see the whole code above.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I reproduce it in another way, you can see the whole code above.
On my win10 WSL2-Ubuntu20.04, the processor is `AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS with Radeon Graphics`. On my Ubuntu20.04 server, the processor is `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8163 CPU @ 2.50GHz`.

Comment: If you loop more than 2, you see the time is similar[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n9nW7c1nb). it is than some work of first iteration goes in timing of the second (which is possible with code rearrangement with optimization).

Comment: @Jarod42, your demo works well! But if I loop four times manually [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yb3Mjqhqc), the first one's time cost is still about a half of the others'. I don't know how could this happen.

Comment: Unfortunately, link doesn't keep track of result, and recompile and relaunch the executable... I got 1500ms 2500ms 2000ms 2000ms for my version. for your version, I got the last iteration which "steal" works from 2nd iteration in similar way. So it doesn't runs slower/faster, just take timing not where you expect (which is allowed with as-is rule, as timing of execution is not a side effect).

Comment: @Jarod42, I've tried several times, the online results is different from the result on my computer, and the time cost seems unstable, changes a lot each time. On my laptop (win10-WSL2-Ubuntu20.04) or server (Ubuntu20.04), if I delete the final `init`, the time cost of the two execution are both `~600ms`. If I keep the final `init`, the time cost of the first one is still `~600ms`, but the second one's is `~1200ms`. I've tested this 100 times, and the time cost results are steady. I think the first execution didn't steal some job from the second, the second one's job just doubled.

Comment: Is timing executable directly (`time my_app`) reproduces that difference?

Comment: @Jarod42, yep, the result of `time ./main` differs from `1.26s` to `1.85s`.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue with WSL on GCC-9.3.0-17 (ubuntu 20.04), but the assembly code change between the two versions does not match with the result of Godbolt using GCC 9.3.0. It seems the very-minor version of GCC 9.3.0-xxx did change the outcomes (or the build parameters).

Comment: @Jarod42 I disagree with the fact that compilers can reorder the instructions between measurements (but processors could theoretically). In fact, such functions are seen as library calls and are not optimized out by GCC. Such function cannot be assumed as pure simply because they can contain systems calls or assembly instructions with side effects. Moreover, I am able to reproduce the problem with a loop executed 20 times that last for about 18 seconds. The fact that there is an `init()` call after the 20-iteration loop slow down all the iterations (by about 0.4 s uniformly per iterations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `init()` is called after the `strange_func()` function call change the generated assembly code of the variable swap (between `s[k]` and `s[k+t]`) in the loop in `strange_func()`! The apparent minor assembly change has a huge impact on the performance as **the loop is very sensitive to micro-optimizations** and the generated code with the `init()` is clearly less efficient. Such a change is likely due to **fragile compiler heuristics** (with a clear *chaotic behaviour* in this specific case) and the fact the `strange_func()` function call is inlined.

---

To understand what is going on, let us analyse the assembly generated by the two variants.

Here is the assembly code of the hot loop without (left) and with (right) `init()`:

```
.L2:                                            |  .L2:
        add     ecx, 1                          |          add     esi, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR 12[rbx+rdx*4], ecx    |          mov     DWORD PTR 12[r12+rdx*4], esi
        cmp     r8d, ecx                        |          cmp     ecx, esi
        jle     .L3                             |          jle     .L3
                                                |   
.L13:                                           |  .L13:
        movsx   r9, eax                         |          movsx   r9, eax
        add     eax, esi                        |          add     eax, edi
        add     ecx, 1                          |          add     esi, 1
        movsx   rdi, eax                        |          movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[r12+r9]
        movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[rbx+r9]        |          movsx   r8, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR 12[rbx+rdx*4], ecx    |          mov     DWORD PTR 12[r12+rdx*4], esi
        movzx   r14d, BYTE PTR 4[rbx+rdi]       |          mov     BYTE PTR 15[rsp], r11b
                                                |          movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[r12+r8]
        mov     BYTE PTR 4[rbx+r9], r14b        |          mov     BYTE PTR 4[r12+r9], r11b
                                                |          movzx   r9d, BYTE PTR 15[rsp]
        mov     BYTE PTR 4[rbx+rdi], r11b       |          mov     BYTE PTR 4[r12+r8], r9b
        cmp     r8d, ecx                        |          cmp     ecx, esi
        jg      .L13                            |          jg      .L13
                                                |   
.L3:                                            |  .L3:
        jne     .L9                             |          jne     .L9
        mov     rsi, r10                        |          mov     rdi, r10
        mov     ecx, r8d                        |          mov     esi, ecx
        .p2align 4,,10                          |          .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3                              |          .p2align 3
                                                |   
.L6:                                            |  .L6:
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR 200[rsi]         |          mov     r11d, DWORD PTR 200[rdi]
        sub     ecx, 1                          |          sub     esi, 1
        sub     rsi, 4                          |          sub     rdi, 4
        mov     DWORD PTR 208[rsi], 0           |          mov     DWORD PTR 208[rdi], 0
        add     edi, 1                          |          lea     r8d, 1[r11]
        mov     DWORD PTR 204[rsi], edi         |          mov     DWORD PTR 204[rdi], r8d
        cmp     ecx, edi                        |          cmp     esi, r8d
        je      .L6                             |          je      .L6
        test    ecx, ecx                        |          test    esi, esi
        je      .L14                            |          je      .L14
                                                |   
.L7:                                            |  .L7:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR 12[rbx+rdx*4]    |          mov     esi, DWORD PTR 12[r12+rdx*4]
        xor     esi, esi                        |          xor     edi, edi
        jmp     .L2                             |          jmp     .L2
        .p2align 4,,10                          |          .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3                              |          .p2align 3
                                                |   
.L9:                                            |  .L9:
        mov     ecx, r8d                        |          mov     esi, ecx
        test    ecx, ecx                        |          test    esi, esi
        jne     .L7                             |          jne     .L7
        .p2align 4,,10                          |          .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3                              |          .p2align 3
```

As we can see, the L13 block contains more instructions with the `init()` call. The rest of the blocks look similar.

Here is a detailed analysis of the blocks *without* `init()`:

```
movsx   r9, eax
add     eax, esi
add     ecx, 1
movsx   rdi, eax
movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[rbx+r9]                ; Perform r11b=s[k]
mov     DWORD PTR 12[rbx+rdx*4], ecx            ; Perform r[N]+=1 (r[N] was stored in ecx previously)
movzx   r14d, BYTE PTR 4[rbx+rdi]               ; Perform r14b=s[k+t]
mov     BYTE PTR 4[rbx+r9], r14b                ; Perform s[k]=r14b
mov     BYTE PTR 4[rbx+rdi], r11b               ; Perform s[k+t]=r11b
cmp     r8d, ecx
jg      .L13
```

Here is a detailed analysis of the blocks *with* `init()`:

```
movsx   r9, eax
add     eax, edi
add     esi, 1
movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[r12+r9]
movsx   r8, eax
mov     DWORD PTR 12[r12+rdx*4], esi            ; Perform r[N]+=1 (r[N] was stored in ecx previously)
mov     BYTE PTR 15[rsp], r11b                  ; Perform c = s[k] (c is stored in memory)
movzx   r11d, BYTE PTR 4[r12+r8]
mov     BYTE PTR 4[r12+r9], r11b                ; Perform s[k]=s[k+t]
movzx   r9d, BYTE PTR 15[rsp]
mov     BYTE PTR 4[r12+r8], r9b                 ; Perform s[k+t]=c
cmp     ecx, esi
jg      .L13
```

We can see that in the first case, GCC is able to swap `s[k]` and `s[k+t]` efficiently while in the second case, GCC use store one value in a temporary location in the stack which is clearly less efficient. An **in-memory swap** is clearly less efficient because of the **data dependency** and **L1 cache latency** (generally about 3-4 cycles on modern x86 AMD/Intel processors).

Whether this is a bug or just a missing optimization of GCC 9.3.0 is still unclear. However, this is very hard to tell without delving into an old version of the GCC code not actively maintained anymore (since March 12, 2020).

A quick workaround solution to this issue is to tell GCC not to inline the function using `__attribute__((noinline))`. Alternatively, it should be possible to *tune GCC heuristic parameters* (using the GCC command line) so that this does not happen. Another solution would be to optimize the loop to *compute several permutations at once* so that such micro-optimizations do not matter so much.

Comment: This problem really confused me for a week! I think I should update gcc to some new version that is actively maintained, like gcc 10.3.0. Thanks a lot!